# how to do nested routes drf-extensions django using uuid instead of id

Tags: django, uuid, nested-routes, drf-extensions

I have two Django models - I will change the name of my models here but the idea is the same.

```py
class Photo(models.Model):
  uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
  image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos')
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Attachment(models.Model):
  uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
  image = models.ImageField(upload_to='attachments')
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  photo = models.ForeignKey(Photo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I have views:

```py
class PhotoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  serializer_class = PhotoSerialzer
  queryset = Photo.objects.all()

class AttachmentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  serializer_class = AttachmentSerializer
  queryset = Attachment.objects.all()
```

and in my `urls.py` file:

```py
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'photo', views.PhotoViewSet, 'photo')
router.register(r'attachments', views.AttachmentViewSet, 'attachment')

class NestedDefaultRouter(NestedRouterMixin, routers.DefaultRouter):
  pass

router = NestedDefaultRouter()

photo_router = router.register('photo', views.PhotoViewSet)
photo_router.register('attachments', views.AttachmentViewSet,
                     basename='photo_attachments', parents_query_lookups=['photo'])
```

I have built a small app where I can upload pictures via admin and upload attachment pictures to those pictures and saved via aws. I've tried letting Django auto create a primary key but for some reason didn't work all too well, that's even if it did - I can't remember, however, with `uuid` this was not an issue as you can see I am using it in my model.

My main error now is that even though I want a url like such:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/dice/c6e53d17-72ba-4a5f-b72e-26b8b2d25230/attachments/
```

which I manually inputted into the address bar after checking the uuid of a photo I have in my database (the uuid being `c6e53d17-72ba-4a5f-b72e-26b8b2d25230`) it just gets all the attachments (even attachments that do not belong to the specified photo using the `uuid` in the url).

According to this small tutorial [here](https://medium.com/@EnterGodMode__/simple-nested-api-using-django-rest-framework-d2dd9f0ff093) I have pretty much the same setup and instead of `id` I have a `uuid`. I am guessing that this is the issue but I'm not sure. I was also thinking that this viewset is a problem:

```py
class AttachmentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  serializer_class = AttachmentSerializer
  queryset = Attachment.objects.all()
```

being that I am getting back every attachment rather than all attachments attached to a specific photo. I figure I should be using something like `filter(photo=photo_uuid)` but according to the tutorial I found I don't have to do that, let alone I don't have access to some param like `photo_uuid` in my `viewset` so how would I filter in the first place.

To re-iterate, my issue is how do I correctly do nested routes if what I am dealing with uuid rather than id being that this I believe is my problem (unless it's something else). If it's something I have to handle now in my `AttachmentViewSet` than how to I correctly `filter` for this. Maybe there is `*args` or `**kwargs` but how then would I access this within my viewset if that is the case.

I did find that I can do

```
def get_queryset(self):
  print(self.kwargs)
  pass
```

When I print I see what I want and can just return what I want by filtering but is the the actual way of doing it?

Answer (score 3):

Set the `lookup_field` to `'uuid'` in your viewset.

```
class AttachmentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    lookup_field = 'uuid'
    serializer_class = AttachmentSerializer
    queryset = Attachment.objects.all()
```

Comment: I tried it but it does not work. When I check for what my self.kwargs contains it is just 'parent_lookup_photo' mapped to a uuid which I can access doing the `get_queryset(self)` I showed in my question. But just setting the `lookup_field = 'uuid'` does not work. I tried to set it to `lookup_field = 'photo'` as well just in case but no luck

Answer (score 1):

> It has been a long time since this question was asked but since it's
> still one of top result of google search(for my query at least) I'm
> writing my take here.

Based on `viewsets` that you've provided, you are missing `NestedViewSetMixin` in you'r viewsets ([documentation](https://chibisov.github.io/drf-extensions/docs/#nested-routes)) which can cause this problem.

So to fix it just make sure you inherit the `NestedViewSetMixin` in you'r `viewset` like below example:

```
class PhotoViewSet(NestedViewSetMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = PhotoSerialzer
    queryset = Photo.objects.all()
```